# Is there any way to determine power rating of a potentiometer?

Tags: power, components, potentiometer

I salvaged a 1kΩ potentiometer from a broken circuit. Is there any way to determine how much power can it take without destroying it?

**EDIT** Picture of the potentiometer:

[image: potentiometer]

The distance between left-most and right-most connector is about 2cm.

Comment: Measuring with `cm`; who does that? :P  Virtually everything in electronics is `mm` or `in`.  Terminal spacing is also fairly pointless, more characteristic for the pot might be the body diameter.  A part number on it would probably be better still.

Comment: @Nick T You mean in this day and age there are people who use `in`? First time I heard about something like that... :) Anyway the point is that I had no easy way to measure diameter, so I put spacing between terminals. Also using `mm` in this case would mean bringing superfluous precision which is a bad thing.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75:  I think that you are completely off the mark.  Notice the little switch contacts at the bottom of the pot.  This is a little pot from something like a transistor radio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm... how big is it? Most potentiometers I have found are rated for 1/2W or 1W. A general rule of thumb though is that you shouldn't be putting much power through it anyway - it should only be controlling a small signal.

Comment: I added a link to picture of the potentiometer (sorry for the quality, my camera is very broken!). The scale shown is in centimeters and it looks like the distance between left-most connector and right-most connector is about 2 cm.

Comment: Probably not much more than 1/2W then. 1W max.

Comment: A side note, if the potentiometer is 1k and is rated for 1/2W, then you should have no more than ~20V across it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's quite unfortunate that introductory electrical engineering courses on my university don't teach students how to actually use real circuit components.

Comment: AndrejaKo: This is an issue at many universities. We got a grant a few years back from the NSF to restructure many of our engineering courses. Now even non-electrical engineers have to take a course where they spend half of the semester in the theoretical world and the other half is spent with a breadboard doing projects.

Answer (score 7):

Please note that the power rating of a potentiometer is for the entire end-to-end resistance. If you use (as is typical) a fraction of the potentiometer's end-to-end resistance, the power is reduced accordingly. The easiest way to think about it is that there is a maximum current through the pot. If you have a 1W 100 ohm potentiometer, the max. current is 100mA (full voltage = 10V); if you are using only 27 ohms of the potentiometer then the max. current is still 100mA and your effective max. power is 0.27W.

Comment: That only applies if you have shorted the wiper to the A or B terminal. Unless there is a significant load on the wiper (which would change the voltage) the power rating is the same throughout the whole range.

Comment: I don't think so. Power limits are constrained by localized heating which is driven by current density.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but the potentiometer dissipates a constant amount of power if it has a constant voltage and no load on the wiper, because the resistance of the pot is constant no matter where the wiper is (it only changes the ratio of the two resistances.)

Comment: We are both correct: I was talking about using it like a rheostat where you use the wiper + one end as a variable resistor, and leave the other terminal disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

That particular pot is similar to those used in old-time hand-held transistor radios. My recollection is that thost are good for perhaps 200 mW at most.

You can often estimate how much power any particular potentiometer can handle based on the physical size and the material that the resistive track is made from. Although experience helps you arrive at an estimate, you can also simply look at a catalog of pots and compare what is in the catalog to what you have. Digikey or Mouser have great on-line catalogs, for example.

Resistive track material is important. You can usually tell if the track is wire-wound by simply rotating the shaft and feeling for the telltale lumps that occur as the wiper moves over the track. If the rotation is smooth, the track is most likely either carbon or carbon film.